# Simplify $\sum_{s=0: s \text{ even }}^\infty \sum_{m=0: \text{ even }}^\infty b_{s,m}x^s(1-x^2)^{\frac{m}{2}}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, summation

I have the following double sum that I am trying to simplify into a single sum:
\begin{align}
\sum_{s=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^\infty b_{2s,2m}x^{2s}(1-x^2)^{m}
\end{align}
where $b_{s,m}$' are coefficients that don't have any specific structure.

But I am having difficulty finding the coefficients of the new sum $\sum_{k} a_k x^k$.

Here is what I tried to do.  First, it is clear that only even coefficients should be considered.

Second, we can use the Binomial theorem to write
\begin{align}
(1-x^2)^{m}= \sum_{i=0}^{m} { m \choose i} (-1)^i x^{2i}
\end{align}
so we can combine everything to
\begin{align}
\sum_{s=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^\infty b_{2s,2m}x^{2s} \sum_{i=0}^{m} { m \choose i} (-1)^i x^{2i}
\end{align}

But at this point, I start getting lost.

**Second approach**
I was thinking we can define
\begin{align}
f(x)=\sum_{s=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^\infty b_{2s,2m}x^{2s}(1-x^2)^{m}
\end{align}
and then find the power series of $f(x)$ around $x=0$. The first coefficients are given by
\begin{align}
a_0&=\frac{f(0)}{1}=b_{0,0}\\
a_1&=\frac{f'(0)}{1}=0\\
a_2&=\frac{f''(0)}{2}=- \sum_{m=0}^\infty m b_{0,m}+ \sum_{m=0}^\infty  b_{2,m}
\end{align}
but again I am stuck with finding other coefficients.

Comment: @user376343 just a coefficient. It doesn't have any specific structure.

Comment: Simplify your life with the substitutions $s = 2t$ and $m = 2n$, where both $t$ and $n$ range over $0, 1, \dots$.

Comment: @Aruralreader  Thanks. Done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum is $\sum_{s=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^\infty b_{2s,2m}x^{2s} \sum_{i=0}^{m} { m \choose i} (-1)^i x^{2i}$

We find the coefficient of $x^{2k}$:

We may have $0 \leq s \leq k$, for a fixed $s$ we require a $x^{2(k-s)}$ term from the $(1-x^2)^m$ factor, in particular we require that $m \geq k-s$. The coefficient of the $x^{2(k-s)}$ term in $(1-x^2)^m$ is ${m \choose (k-s)} (-1)^{k-s}$, so the coefficient of $x^{2k}$ is $\sum_{s=0}^k \sum_{m \geq (k-s)} b_{2s,2m} {m \choose (k-s)} (-1)^{k-s} = c_k$, the final sum is $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_kx^{2k}$

Comment: Can one establish a recursion between $c_k$? There seem to be some terms that repeat.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, could you specify what sort of recurrence you're looking for/what terms repeat?

Comment: I mean. It look like we can write $c_{k+1}$ in terms of $c_{k}$. Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: You might be interested in the following question that is related to this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4183166/if-sum-s-0-infty-sum-m-0-infty-b-s-mx2s1-x2m-0-for-all-x-i